# How to run programs from a bash script on different GPUs?

Tags: bash, slurm, sbatch

I usually run two separate jobs (program1 and program2) on two different GPUs.

I would like to be able to run these two jobs from a single bash script but still on two different GPUs **with a slurm .out file for each programs**. Is this possible?

```sh
#!/bin/bash -l
#SBATCH --time=1:00:00
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:v100:1
#SBATCH --mem=90g
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=6 -N 1

program1
```

```sh
#!/bin/bash -l
#SBATCH --time=1:00:00
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:v100:1
#SBATCH --mem=90g
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=6 -N 1

program2
```

The script below seems to run both programs on the same GPU with a single .out file as output.

```sh
#!/bin/bash -l
#SBATCH --time=1:00:00
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:v100:1
#SBATCH --mem=90g
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=6 -N 1

program1 &
program2 &
wait
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First way**

You could write a submit script that gets the name of the executable as a command line argument and another script that calls the submit script. The submit script "submit.sh" could look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
#SBATCH --time=1:00:00
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:v100:1
#SBATCH --mem=90g
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=6 -N 1

$1
```

The second script "run_all.sh" could look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

sbatch submit.sh program1
sbatch submit.sh program2
```

Now you can start your jobs with:`$ ./run_all.sh`

**Second way**

You don't have to use scripts to provide all the information for slurm. It is possible to pass the job information as arguments from the sbatch call: `sbatch [OPTIONS(0)...] [ : [OPTIONS(N)...]] script(0) [args(0)...]`

A script like this then could be useful:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
slurm_opt= --time=1:00:00 --gres=gpu:v100:1 --mem=90g --cpus-per-task=6 -N 1 --wrap
sbatch $slurm_opt program1
sbatch $slurm_opt program2
```

Note the `--wrap` option. It allows you to have any executable not just a script after it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Isn't there a way to do this from a single .sh file and have separate slurm.out files for each task?

Comment: I updated the answer with a way that only uses one script. It is a little bit less flexible but it can easily be used for simple job submissions.